# How do I get pretty error messages in RStudio?

Tags: r, runtime-error, rstudio, traceback

When working in RStudio (version 0.99.482 and 1.0.136), if I source a file and an error occur I just get the error message without any context. If the file is longer than a few lines of code, that informaiton is largely useless. What I want to know when an error occurs is the following:

1. What function threw the error? Preferably what function I called from my script, not something burried deep inside a package.
2. On what line of my file did the error occur?

This seems like a very basic thing for a scripting language to do, but yet I am unable to find an easy solution. Yes, I am aware of the `traceback()` function, but (a) it is a hassle to call it every time there is an error, and (b) the output is massive and not that helpful.

Comment: Regarding the "to broad" close vote: It is possible that this requires a lot of coding to solve. But just knowing that no, there is no easy fix, would be very useful. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and for something this basic I highly suspect that there already is a solution somewhere.

Comment: Please, be more specific. It's didfficult to understand what your issue is as I do get these information in case of errors. Does the error happen when you source the file or when you run your code? Do you have one large file? Do you use functions? Which versions of R and RStudio are you using?

Comment: I don't get the information. My version has been added to the question - will try to upgrade and see if that solves it. I want to get this info for all and any error that occurs when I source a file. Currently, it happends for no errors at all. Its not about any specific error - it is about getting this information whenever an error occur in a sourced file. So small file or large file doesnt really matter.

Comment: @UweBlock Upgrading to version 1.0.136 does not help.